# interpolation of fortnightly annual temperature data into hourly measurements in matlab

Tags: matlab, time, interpolation

I have a dataset of annual temperature measurements recorded at fortnightly intervals. The data looks similar to the following:

```
t = 1:14:365;
% GENERATE DATA
y = 1 + (30-1).*rand(1,length(t));
y1 = 20*sin(2*pi*t/max(t));        % Annual variation °C
y1(y1<0) = [];
tt = 365/14;
time = 1:tt:365;
plot(time,y1,'-o');
```

where it clearly follows a annual temperature cycle.

From this I am wondering if it is possible to add a sine function (which would represent a diurnal temperature range) onto the data? For example, from the fortnightly data, if we were to interpolate the series to have 8760 measurements i.e. hourly measurements, for the series to be believable it would need to be characterized by a diurnal temperature cycle in addition to the annual temperature cycle. Furthermore, the diurnal temperature cycle would need to be a function of the temperature measurements at that time i.e. would be greater in the summer than in winter. So maybe it would be better to firstly use linear interpolation to get the data to represents hourly intervals and then add the sine function. Is there a method for writing this into a script? or does anyone have an opinion on how to accurately achieve this?

Comment: All of what you are wondering about seems eminently do-able to me and, in Matlab, you have an appropriate toolset for doing it all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment could you provide further information i.e. which toolset are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to Matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could first interpolate your data (down to 1 hours) using something like

```
x = 1:inv(24):365;
T_interp = interp1(t,y1,x,'spline');
```

Check out Matlab documentation for [interp1](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) (example 2)

and then add a sine onto it. The following a sine of period 1 (24 hours) with amplitude A, with a minimum at 3am.

```
T_diurn = -A*sin(2*pi*x+(3/24)*2*pi);
```

Then

```
T_total = T_diurn + T_interp;
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be along the same lines at what I was thinking. Although I was hoping of also controlling the amplitude of the sine wave in relation to the actual temperature at a particular day of year. For example, the amplitude will be greater when the temperature is higher, currently the amplitude is equal throughout the year, this would not be realistic in environmental time series. Thanks again

Comment: You can change the amplitude A as a function of the baseline (mean) temperature. Or whatever you fancy. Now that you've the tools, it's up to you to play with them :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First: you know that good-looking plots are the most misleading things in existence? Interpolating data gathered every 14 days so that it will look like data collected every *hour* is considered at least bad practice most circles...

Having said that, I would use `spline`s to do the interpolation -- they are a lot more flexible when it comes to changing from fortnightly and hourly to some arbitrary other combination, plus the annual temperature variation will be a lot smoother.

Here's how:

```
% Create spline through data
pp = spline(time, y1);


% define diurnal variation (this one is minimal at 4 AM)    
T_diurn = @(t) -A*cos(2*pi*(t-(4/24)));

% plot example 
t = 150 : 1/24 : 250;    
plot( t, ppval(pp,t)+T_diurn(t) , 'b')
```